# Selecting the direct first element after another element in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="form">
    <form>
       <textarea id="text"></textarea>
       <span class="error">select this</span>
       <span class="error">don't select this</span>
    </form>
</div>
```

In CSS, how can I select only the *first* `span` element directly after the `textarea` element and *not* select the other `span` elements after the first?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use an [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators):

```css
#text + span {
    /* Styles */
}
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/wjmvJ/).

**Update** (see comments)

To target the second `span` you can simply add another adjacent sibling combinator to the selector:

```css
#text + span + span {
    /* Styles */
}
```

Comment: Just curious, then what happens if I want to select only the second span element?

Comment: [`#text + span + span`](http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/ngrZz/1/)

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Thanks for the syntax highlighting edits :) I never remember to put those comments in.

Comment: Probably because of the awkward syntax. Hopefully SO introduces fenced code blocks soon allowing to put the syntax right after the first fence

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`+` (adjacent sibling)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) selector:

```
textarea + span { ... }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/ngrZz/